# Cloudflare Pages .html redirect causes Redirection Error for Google indexing

Tags: seo, cloudflare, google-search-console, google-crawlers, cloudflare-pages

It seems that if I have in my page links that use the `.html` extension, Google Search Console's crawling or live test will fail to retrieve those resources, with a Redirection Error message under `Page resources: x/x couldn't be loaded`, even though a client browser can get the results just fine.

Side note: If those `.html` URLs are tested directly for a live URL test, they show they can be retrieved and can be indexed.

Is there any solution to this besides removing all the `.html` path extensions in production? Keeping the extensions is for the local testing Python server.

Comment: You mention a `redirect` in the question title. Where is a redirect happening exactly? Also do you have `link rel="canonical"` tags on these pages? And if so what is the value of those canonical URLs?

Comment: Redirect from `.html` to its nameless paths is a standard Pages feature that cannot be opted out as per docs: https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/serving-pages/#route-matching